# How to define a row-major sparse vector in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

This should be a simple question but documentation does not help: I'd like to define a sparse vector in Eigen so that's it's stored in a row-major format.

This produces a column-major vector:

```
Eigen::SparseVector<float> vec;
```

I've tried using

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, Eigen::Dynamic> RowVector;
RowVector vec(size);
```

but it runs into runtime issues later on. Is there a simple way to defined dynamically-sized row-major sparse vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second template parameter of the SparseVector is the storage order (or actually, the options). So you would write `Eigen::SparseVector<float, Eigen::RowMajor> rowVec;`. See the docs [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseVector.html).

Comment: Thanks I'd add these doc links: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html#title9 and https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html